# How to implement a find_or_create method for a struct containing a hashmap with mutable references

Tags: hashmap, rust

I'm having problems with a struct containing a hashmap in rust.

Lets say I have the following types:

```
pub type KeyType i32;
pub enum StatusType { Locked, Unlocked } 

pub struct Entry {
  key: KeyType,
  status: StatusType
}

pub struct Manager<'a> {
    map: HashMap<KeyType, &'a mut Entry>
}
```

I want to define a method on Manager that takes a key and returns either a unlocked entry if not found, or the existing entry if it exists. Here is the pseudo code:

```
impl<'a> Manager<'a> {
    pub fn find_or_create_entry(&'a mut self, key: KeyType) -> &'a mut Entry {
    match self.map.get(&key) {
      Some(e) => e,
      None => {
        // create new entry, add to map, and return mutable ref
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how this works in Rust. Any pointers?

Comment: Have you seen the [entry api](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html)? Something like `map.entry(&key).or_insert(default)`.

Comment: no, this looks much better! would you happen to know how to create a mutable reference to a new Entry instance with lifetime 'a?

Comment: I'm really new at this and the lifetimes are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by changing the type of the HashMap to `HashMap<KeyType,Box<Entry>>`, and implemented the method as follows:

```
pub fn get_or_create_entry(& mut self, key: LockKey) -> &mut LockEntry {                                                                              
  let e = Box::new(LockEntry{key: key, status: LockStatus::Unlocked});
  self.lock_table.entry(key).or_insert(e)
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You should be able to get away with `HashMap<KeyType, Entry>` unless you truly need the `Entry`'s to not move in memory. In any case, there's no way to create a `&mut` reference to a local variable and store it like that: the local variable will be destroyed as soon as the function returns and the reference will be left dangling, pointing at invalid memory.